# WCF RESTful Web Service under IIS - URL Rewriting (getting 404 errors)

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewriting

I have a WCF RESTful web service (using the webHttpBinding) running under IIS, exposed via an SVC file (accessed at http://projectserver/BlarghService/BlarghService.svc).

I can access service endpoints through the URI templates defined on each service by using the BlarghService.svc file, like so:

```
http://projectserver/BlarghService/BlarghService.svc/accounts/
http://projectserver/BlarghService/BlarghService.svc/accounts/342432
```

Both of these work fine.

However it's important I remove implementation details from the URIs, so I used IIS URI rewriting module and set up a wildcard rewriting rule which tacks everything after /BlarghService/ to the end of BlarghService.svc, so the following are transformed into the earlier representations:

```
http://projectserver/BlarghService/accounts/
http://projectserver/BlarghService/accounts/342432
```

However, when I request these resources I get 404 errors. These are not IIS-generated 404 errors, but those generated by ASP.NET itself (so IIS is correctly rewriting the URL). However ASP.NET decides to check if the specified file ("BlarghService.svc/accounts/342432") exists in the filesystem which it should be passing it on to my web service.

But the strange thing is when I copy the reported "Requested URL" (from the ASP.NET 404 error) back into the address bar, it works fine.

So what's going on?

EDIT: Here is my web.config (located in the "BlarghService" directory)

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <!-- Currently ASP.NET steps in says it's a 404 error when it should be handled by BlarghService.svc, I've no idea why. -->
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="BlarghServiceRewriteRule" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="BlarghService.svc/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true">
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="http://projectserver/BlarghService" />
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
        <service name="Foo.Blargh.Api.BlarghService" behaviorConfiguration="BlarghServiceBehavior">

            <endpoint name="BlarghEndpoint" address="BlarghService.svc" behaviorConfiguration="BlarghEndpointBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RH.Blargh.Api.BlarghService" />

        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="BlarghServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="BlarghEndpointBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: check to make sure you aren't using an aspx button or form that is trying to submit in addition to your wcf call.  

Also, if you are not using .ajax and jQuery to make the call to the wcf service, I would strongly encourage you to pursue that approach.

Comment: There aren't any ASP.NET components in the web service. I got the error when making a GET request for a rewritten URL from a web browser.

Comment: can you post your url rewrite match pattern and rewrite url?

Comment: I've edited my post to show the relevant sections of web.config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: It turns out that WCF can only respond on one particular HTTP host header at a time, and that my URL rewriting was involved in responding to some host headers but not others. By standardising on a single set of host-headers and reformulating my rewrite rules accordingly it started working.

Comment: Dai, it's been a long time, but maybe you can still share more details? Any chance you still have fixed rewrite rules and can share them? I've got the same problem and would be very glad to understand how to fix it.

Comment: @Ivan my webservice/IIS website was bound to "http://www.fooservice.com" and "http://fooservice.com" - I decided to remove the binding for "www.fooservice.com" and it was working fine for the "fooservice.com" binding.

Comment: Thanks, Dai! I'll dig for differences between rewritten and direct HTTP requests by Wireshark.

Comment: Found the root cause of my problem - IIS was using local handler for *.svc files, had to remove it in local Web.config (  <handlers><remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" /></handlers>)